# Visual Filesystem Directory Tree String

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree, directory, filesystems

I'm looking for a module that can take a path like `dirTree('./')` and provide a visual string of a directory like this.

```
photos
├── summer
│   └── june
│       └── windsurf.jpg
└── winter
    └── january
        ├── ski.png
        └── snowboard.jpg
```

I've done some extensive research into the subject but can't find anything that does this. The only thing that comes close is [mihneadb/node-directory-tree](https://github.com/mihneadb/node-directory-tree) however it doesn't produce a string, it produces JSON. I can put the work in traversing the object returned with `directory-tree` but this has to exist somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of software that does exactly what you want, however it's not written in node.

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/